# Multiple fact tables per Cube OLAP

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I want to calculate the "stock turnover rate" KPI which depend on two measures in two differents table facts (Amount from sales fact and physical quantity from inventory fact). So, my question is the following-

> Do I have to regroup the two facts in the same cube OLAP, or is there another way to do this? knowing that everyone recommend to have one fact table per cube.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any dimensions that the Fact tables share?

I don't think that being recommended to have 1 Fact table per Cube is correct. There is no reason why you cant have multiple Fact tables or Measure groups.

Comment: Yes, there are, a cube define a business process, but stock management and sales aren't the same process. what do you think ?